# Submitting data from a form to django view

Tags: python, django, html

When I open the html file it displays as expected and when I enter data in the text box and submit, It redirects me to `localhost/myapp/output/` but why is the data I enter in the text box not submitted for example like `localhost/myapp/output/data_I_submitted`

My basic html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>db app</title>
</head>
<body>
{% csrf_token %}
<form action="output/" method="post" name="Input">
Data : <input type="text" name="text">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my `app.urls` file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.index),
    url(r'^output/(?P<text>\w+)/$',views.return_data)
)
```

Finally the **view**:

```
def return_data(request,text):
    return HttpResponse('entered text ' + text)
```

Comment: Why don't you have `csrf_token`?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac *Updated* but still no luck :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your goal is only getting the text on the form:

change your view to

```
def return_data(request):
    return HttpResponse('entered text:' + request.POST['text'])
```

edit your urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^output/$', views.return_data)
)
```

and your template

```
<form action="output/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
...
</form>
```

Comment: +1 Your answer was nearly correct but please add the fact that I have to put a `csrf_token` inside the `<form>` tag inorder to help someone else...

Comment: What is `csrf_token`?

Comment: Protection against [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/)

Answer (score 1):

you'd better review data submitting in forms.
with two methods you can submit forms data with your request to the forms action attribute:

**GET**: like http://www.google.com/?q=keyword+to+search
you can access the "keyword+to+search" by:

```
request.GET['q']
#or better is:
request.GET.get('q', None)
```

the *text* arguement is not passed to url pattern. so not accessible in this way

**POST**: 
in this method the data is not in request url.
so to access the forms data submittin by POST method
try this

```
request.POST['text'] (
#or better is: 
request.POST.get('text', None)
```

but it is **highly recommended** to use Django forms instead of direct accessing from request.POST or request.GET

so check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/