# How to update a form value and submit the updated form using JS

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, materialize

I have this form:

```
<form name = "myform" method='POST' >{% csrf_token %}
<div class="input-field col s6"> {{form.GenerateDate.as_hidden}}</div>
<div class="input-field col s6"> {{form.Product.as_hidden}}</div>
<div class="input-field col s6"> {{form.Link.as_hidden}}</div>
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" id="usercontent"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s6"> {{form.Status.as_hidden}}</div>
<center><input type='submit' value='add' class="waves-effect waves-light btn" ></input></center>

</form>
```

I am loading the value in textarea using this script:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$('#textarea1').val('{{form.UserContent.value}}');
</script>
```

The value is displayed as it is in the DB. But now I want to update this {{form.UserContent.Value}} in the form and using JS then POST it again using the submit button and let django save the new value.

But it stores "None" instead!

I am using materialize css and django 1.11 Textarea is a must for my use.

For HTML advisers here is the code :

```
<form name = "myform" method='POST' >
<div class="input-field col s6" id="Product"> </div>
<div class="input-field col s6" id = "Link"> </div>
<div class="input-field col s6" id = "Status"> </div>
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" id="usercontent"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<center><input type='submit' value='add' class="waves-effect waves-light btn" ></input></center>

</form>

<script  type="text/javascript">
$('#textarea1').val('abcdef');
</script>
```

I want to update abcdef to qwerty in the form after hitting submit button using JS here.

Comment: It does not make sense. You are trying to input something generated by Django with the help of JavaScript? Why not just do `<textarea>{{form.UserContent.value}}</textarea>`? or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: it does not load the value in an auto resizable textarea if I do it your way. I am successfully able to load the value here with JS. But I want to update the value now and push it in the DB.

Comment: Are you taking something from the DB and loading it directly into a textarea only in order to post it back to the server? That seems like an inefficient methodology, if so; it might be wise to reconsider your approach altogether; what is it you're trying to do, and why does a web user need to be involved in what seems to be intended as an automatic process? As for the body of the question, if the Django aspect is irrelevant, could you simplify your question to exclude it? Update the textarea value from what/where; after applying the value from `{{form.UserContent.value}}`?

Comment: @FredGandt I am loading the value in the form to show the user its previous version and later the user will update the value in the same box and hit the submit button. But! loading the previous value in the Materialize Textarea is only possible through the script mentioned above. Now how do I update the value while the new form is submitted? Are you getting my point?

Comment: On submit, the values of the form can be accessed by various scripting languages, and will contain the user submitted changes to the value in the textarea. Are you asking how to update the DataBase?

Comment: @FredGandt Nope, I am asking how to submit the form again with the updated values?

Comment: Thank you for your simplification and clarification edits. If the textarea is delivered to the user filled with a value fetched from the DB, and they then change that value and submit the form, the server should handle the form submission in the same way as _"normal"_ and the changed value will be part of the formData. Is the problem that you don't know how to process formData, and if so, what language will your form be posting to (there's no `action` on your `<form>`?

Comment: Some documentation you might find useful: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688047/submitting-data-from-a-form-to-django-view assuming you're submitting to a Python/Django backend.